# Mozilla image flicker on source change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I have an image preloader, and it's preloads n images in the future. And i can see the loaded in the network inspector. Then i have this code when i scroll down:

```
$scope.image = Preloader.getNext();
```

Which replaces the current image with already loaded one. And the getNext() just return Image() object.
And then i have this in my view:

```
 <img id="frames" ng-src="{{image.src}}" />
```

Which displays the current image. On every browser(including IE) this works fine, but only in mozilla this has this annoying flicker:

[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/yvW8JDj.gifv)

Do you have any idea why is this happening, and even better how to go about fixing it?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem with ff flickering

Comment: @Grant Yes, i fixed it switching to canvas and rendering images.

Comment: thanks, that fixed the issue. You should post that as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by switching image rendering to canvas instead of dom.